# Critique my Lisp, please

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have created a nice little routine:

```
(defun unzip (seq)
  "Takes an even-length list and breaks it apart by evens/odd index"
  (let ((oddresult '())
    (evenresult '()))
    (loop for n from 0 to (- (length seq) 1) do
      (if (oddp n)
          (push (nth n seq) oddresult)
        (push (nth n seq) evenresult)))
    (list (reverse oddresult) (reverse evenresult))))
```

And to use it:

```
CL-USER> (unzip '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
((2 4 6) (1 3 5))
```

However, I am keenly aware of my ability to <s>write</s>botch C++ in any language, and would like some analysis of my `unzip` for good Common Lisp style.

Comment: It wouldn't be polite to tease someone about their speech empediment.

Comment: @Paul Nathan The result ought to be `((1 3 5) (2 4 6))`, right?

Comment: Lisp reminds me of the ancient Greek, where it has no real utility (besides Emacs), only a few people are able to use the language, while at the same time the same people, the most educated ones, love to talk about it, and its style, for hours :-)

Comment: @ring0: In any programming language, there is an idiom and a correct style, and there are those interested in learning and discussing it. There is even a neologism - "pythonic".

Comment: "@Frank Shearar: Your understanding of the unzip method is not correct. If you read the doc text, it seems you left off the last word, namely index :)" <-- @leppie, I'd hoped my comment showed I'd realised my mistake. At least one person mistook my answer as a correct solution, so I deleted it. (My solution split a list of integers into odds & evens; the poster's, well, unzipping a list: split the list one-for-one into two sublists.)

Comment: Too many parenthesis.

Comment: @PN Are you comparing Lisp and Python?

Comment: This isn't `unzip` we know it, Jim.

Comment: @Dave: If you don't like Lisp, why don't you just ignore questions tagged lisp? That way you don't need to pollute the conversations of people actually interested in lisp.

Comment: @Frank: I think Dave meant it as a joke.

Comment: @ring0: "Is this pythonic?" means "Is this idiomatic python? Is this written in the python way?" PN's asking "Is this idiomatic CL? Is this written in the CL way?"

Comment: @BoltClock: +1 for not being humor-impaired.

Comment: @Dave: I got my Pundit badge mainly for talking crap a lot :)

Comment: @BoltClock: I wasn't aware of that badge. I think I have a new goal :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review.

Answer (score 13):

First note that `'()` and `()` are equivalent, since empty list is self evaluating and equal to `NIL`, and in any case you don't need those in [LET](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) because `NIL` is implied by `(let (variable) ...) syntax, which is a reason why you need a parenthesis around each binding when giving the a starting value.

Not that using `LET` is necessary for this case. Using [LOOP](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) features more extensively this function can be written as:

```
(defun unzip (seq)
  "Takes an even-length list and breaks it apart by evens/odd index"
  (loop for n from 0
        for element in seq
        if (oddp n)
          collect element into oddresult
        else
          collect element into evenresult
        finally (return (list oddresult evenresult))))
```

Personally I prefer [iterate](http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) for most iteration, using which it can be written as:

```
(defun unzip (seq)
  "Takes an even-length list and breaks it apart by evens/odd index"
  (iter (for element in seq)
        (for n from 0)
        (if (oddp n)
            (collect element into oddresult)
            (collect element into evenresult))
        (finally (return (list oddresult evenresult)))))
```

or even:

```
(defun unzip (seq)
  "Takes an even-length list and breaks it apart by evens/odd index"
  (iter (generate element in seq)
        (collect (next element) into evenresult)
        (collect (next element) into oddresult)
        (finally (return (list oddresult evenresult)))))
```

EDIT: Additional notes: The name `unzip` conventionally denotes a slightly different function. The argument name should really be `list`, since `seq` would suggest the the function also takes vectors. While it is possible to have functions operating on generalized sequences, it is usually not recommended, since lists and vectors have different performance characteristics. In particular, random access through `NTH` is linear time for lists, which means you should almost never use it. Even if the time cost is insignificant it usually indicates you should be using a different datastructure.

Comment: Pretty. Mention *nth* being bad and you get a +1

Answer (score 8):

The function `(nth n list)` needs to traverse the list to access the nth element, an O(n) operation, and it's called O(n) times in your implementation, making the whole process O(n^2).  You can accomplish the same in O(n):

```
(defun unzip (list)
  (loop for (x y) on list by #'cddr
        collect x into a
        collect y into b
        finally (return (list a b))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at your code:

```
(defun unzip (seq)
  "Takes an even-length list and breaks it apart by evens/odd index"

 ; you name the variable seq (sequence), but the documentation mentions
 ; only lists. Sequence is in CL an abstraction over lists and vectors. 

 ; also nothing in the code really says that the list needs to be even-length  

  (let ((oddresult  '())
        (evenresult '()))
    (loop for n from 0 to (- (length seq) 1) do  ; you can iterate BELOW         
      (if (oddp n)
          (push (nth n seq) oddresult)    ; <- NTH is inefficient for lists
        (push (nth n seq) evenresult)))   ; <- NTH is inefficient for lists
    (list (reverse oddresult)             ; <- return multiple values
          (reverse evenresult))))
```

Here is a version for lists:

```
(defun unzip (list &aux oddresult evenresult (odd t))
  "Takes a list and breaks it apart by evens/odd index"
  (dolist (element list (values (reverse oddresult) (reverse evenresult)))
    (if (setf odd (not odd))
        (push element oddresult)
      (push element evenresult))))
```

Example (note that indexing is zero based in CL, I changed the example to make it less confusing):

```
CL-USER 10 > (unzip '(0 1 2 3 4 5))
(1 3 5)
(0 2 4)
```

Here is a version that expects an even-length list and uses LOOP:

```
(defun unzip (list)
  "Takes an even-length list and breaks it apart by evens/odd index"
  (loop for (even odd) on list by #'cddr
        collect even into evenresult
        collect odd  into oddresult
        finally (return (values oddresult evenresult))))
```

Answer (score 2):

The only bad thing I can see is `nth`. You should iterate thru the list instead as `nth` will likely need to iterate the list anyways. Forget about arrays and array indexing  :)

Unfortunately, I dont know the how to do that in Lisp, but in Scheme, you would just use a named `let`.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this either with LOOP or with a recursive function.

For a LOOP-based solution, @Ramarren has pretty much nailed it.

If it's not critical to know what came from even indexes and what came from odd, I'd use something like:

```
(defun unzip (list &optional acc1 acc2)
   (if seq
       (unzip (cdr list) acc2 (cons (car list) acc1)))
       (list (nreverse acc1) (nreverse acc2))))
```

If it's necessary to know what came from odd or even indexes, I'd wrap that UNZIP in a helper function that compares CAR of list and CAAR of the return value. If they're the same, pass it back out, otherwise swap the two lists in the result-list.

Comment: Using recursion is not a good idea, since one would need tail recursion optimization. Which is not a part of plain standard CL and is invoked differently in each implementation which supports it.

Answer (score 1):

- Rather than looping over the elements of the list, you should use `for-each` or `car` and `cdr` to iterate over the list until it's empty.
- I would not call it `unzip` because it isn't the opposite of `zip`.

Edit: To be more specific, I expect `zip` to take a pair of lists and return a list of pairs, so `unzip` should take a list of pairs and return a pair of lists. I would expect it to look like this example I found:

```
(defun unzip (list)
  (let ((a '())
        (b '()))
    (for-each (lambda (i) (push (first i) a) (push (second i) b)) list)
    (values (nreverse a) (nreverse b))))
```

Comment: Given an plist, it _is_ the opposite of `zip`, isn't it? But in the general case, no.

Answer (score 1):

Scheme version, just for target practice. :-) (Requires SRFI 1's `fold` function.)

```
(define (unzip l)
  (define (iter e v)
    (list (not (car v)) (caddr v) (cons e (cadr v))))
  (define (swap-if p a b)
    (if p (list b a) (list a b)))
  (map reverse
       (apply swap-if (fold iter '(#t () ()) l))))
```

To change the order of the returned lists (i.e., even-indexed elements first), simply change the `#t` to `#f`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution, using recursion:

```
(defun unzip (l)
  (labels ((every-other (l) (if l (cons (car l) (every-other (cddr l))))))
    (list (every-other (cdr l)) (every-other l))))
```

First, we define a helper function every-other that takes every other element from a list. Then, we run this function on the original list with the first item skipped, and on the original list.

Drawback: Due to recursion it may stack overflow for large lists. If it must handle large lists see @Vatine for a tail-recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a loop version that isn't sensitive to odd-length inputs, it's only a minor variation of @huaiyuan's answer, with an added when clause:

```
(defun unzip (list)
  (loop for (x y) on list by #'cddr
     collect x into a
     when y
     collect y into b
     finally (return (list a b))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution:

```
(defun unzip (seq &optional oddresult evenresult)
  (if (null seq)
      (list (reverse oddresult) (reverse evenresult))
    (if (oddp (car seq))
        (unzip (cdr seq) (cons (car seq) oddresult) evenresult)
      (unzip (cdr seq) oddresult (cons (car seq) evenresult)))))
```

Comment: You're supposed to split on odd or even indexes, not odd or even elements.